# search data into one table in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i trying to search  item name or item code in database into different rows in one table. **The admin can search items, through item name or code.**

But when i write this code to search data. They show me blank result. The question is how to i do this.
how i correct ***"like query"***. The problem is here

```
->like('item_name',$quer)
 ->like('item_code',$query)
```

Here is the code:

```
function prd_search($query)
 {
        $q= $this->db->from('purchase')
            ->like('item_name',$query)
            ->like('item_code',$query)
            ->get();
           return $q->result();
        }
```

Comment: You need `OR` `or_like()` operation not `AND`

Comment: Refer: http://www.bsourcecode.com/codeigniter/codeigniter-select-query/#get-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    $q= $this->db->from('purchase')
                 ->group_start()
                    ->like('item_name',$query)
                    ->or_like('item_code',$query)
                 ->group_end()
                 //you can other conditions here.
             ->get();
    return $q->result();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `OR`operation

Your code is :

```
function prd_search($query)
{
$q= $this->db->from('purchase')
    ->like('item_name',$query)
    ->or_like('item_code',$query)
    ->get();
   return $q->result();
}
```